# Toggle closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle element on click on `.event` block. Unfortunately it only works when I click on the target element.
`metadata` should toggle when click on `event`.

```js
$(".event").on("click", function (event) {
    $(event.target).closest(".metadata").toggle();
});
```

```css
.hilight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.tright {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="event" id="event_100">
    <div class="row summary">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-1"> <span class="badge badge-info">special</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-11">Error excepturi cumque aspernatur amet enim maxime nisi et.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row metadata">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="event" id="event_99">
    <div class="row summary">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-1"> <span class="badge badge-info">special</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-11">Error excepturi cumque aspernatur amet enim maxime nisi et.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row metadata">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="event" id="event_98">
    <div class="row summary">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-1"> <span class="badge badge-warning">special</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-11">Error excepturi cumque aspernatur amet enim maxime nisi et.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row metadata">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See DOC: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

closest() looking for ancestor, `event.target` returning clicked element, you should use instead:

`$(this).find(".metadata").toggle();`

```js
$(".event").on("click", function (event) {
    $(this).find(".metadata").toggle();
});
```

```css
.hilight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.tright {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="event" id="event_100">
    <div class="row summary">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-1"> <span class="badge badge-info">special</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-11">Error excepturi cumque aspernatur amet enim maxime nisi et.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row metadata">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="event" id="event_99">
    <div class="row summary">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-1"> <span class="badge badge-info">special</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-11">Error excepturi cumque aspernatur amet enim maxime nisi et.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row metadata">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="event" id="event_98">
    <div class="row summary">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-1"> <span class="badge badge-warning">special</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-11">Error excepturi cumque aspernatur amet enim maxime nisi et.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row metadata">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="meta-key tright">key</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="meta-value">value</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I always thought it was traveling down and not up.